# Unknown column 'count' in 'field list'

Tags: c#, mysql

I try to make a login form in C# with MySQL database but i get this error:
***Unknown column 'count' in 'field list'***. What can I do?

Image with error:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace ScoalaIT
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string myConnection = "server=localhost;database=test;uid=root;password=123456";
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);


            //string StrQuery1 = "Select count from users where user='" + txtUser.Text + "' and parola='" + txtParola.Text + "'";
            MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("Select count from users where user='" + txtUser.Text + "' and parola='" + txtParola.Text + "'", connection);
            //MySqlDataAdapter MyAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            connection.Open();
            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            int count = 0;
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                count++;
            }
            if (count == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ok");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Nu ok");
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: it is `count(*)`, also use parameters with your query, you are open to  [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this...

```
"Select count from
```

to this...

```
"Select count(*) from
```

and then read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection becuase you're sure to suffer from it.

Comment: Works, but you can login with a wrong user/pass too.

Comment: Because you are not checking whether count is non-zero, you're just checking whether you got any rows back. Which you always will! To make your code work, replace count(*) with a field from the users table, maybe 'user' - that way you will get a row back when a login and password match.

Comment: @user3421239, you need to use `command.ExectueScalar` get the returned number. Check if it is 1 then you got the records, otherwise invalid username/password

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :** `count` is reserved word

**Solution :** you could wrap up the resereved words inside the back ticks.

Try This:

```
MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("Select `count` from users where 
 user='" + txtUser.Text + "' and parola='" + txtParola.Text + "'", connection);
```

**Suggestion:** your query is open to sql injection attacks i'd suggest to use parameterised queries to avoid them.

**Note:** if you want to get the total count of matching users then you should use `count(*)` instead of `count`

Try This:

```
MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("Select count(*) from users where 
   user='" + txtUser.Text + "' and parola='" + txtParola.Text + "'", connection);
```

**Using Parameterised queries: Complete Solution**

```
MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("Select count(*) from users where 
   user=@username and parola=@password", connection);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username",txtUser.Text);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pasword",txtParola.Text);
int totalCount = Convert.ToInt32(myCommand.ExecuteScalar());

        if (totalCount > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ok");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nu ok");
        }
```

Comment: @Downvoter: could you please explain me the problem.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I think mysql doesn't uses square brackets for reserve words, instead its back ticks ```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[count] from users where user='g' and parola='g'' at line 1

Comment: @user3421239: try with the Parameterised queries , check my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

`count` is a MySQL function. This means you shouldn't name a column that. But if you do, you *must* wrap it in ticks:

```
MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("Select `count` from users where user='" + txtUser.Text + "' and parola='" + txtParola.Text + "'", connection);
```

If you're trying to get the number of rows that your `WHERE` caluse matches, you need to count something for this to work:

```
MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("Select count(*) from users where user='" + txtUser.Text + "' and parola='" + txtParola.Text + "'", connection);
```

Comment: As you wrote that comment I updated my answer to cover that situation